# Do record types affect the performance of a migration with kingswaysoft?

Tags: ssis, salesforce, kingswaysoft

I have a migration I am running with about ~10 tasks. Each task takes about 5 minutes to process 50k-100k records and migrate them to salesforce. One task in particular is taking a much longer time to process than the other tasks.

This task is migrating data to a simple custom object with only 5 custom fields. The only difference is that this destination object has record types enabled and the other destination objects do not.

Do record types impact the performance?

SQL from ole db source. This query takes 1 second to execute and retrieve 55k rows

```
SELECT 
    rh.RevisionHardwareID AS 'Machine_Information_Id__c',
    COALESCE(lmi.Name, lmz.Name) as 'License_Method__c',
    rhd.Servers AS 'Servers__c',
    rhd.Managers AS 'Managers__c',
    COALESCE(rhd.LicenseCount, rhs.CPUCount, rhz.MIPS, rhi.CPW) AS 'Quantity__c',
    CASE
        WHEN rhd.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN '0122J00000023maQAA'
        WHEN rhi.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN '0122J00000023mcQAA'
        WHEN rhz.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN '0122J00000023mdQAA'
        WHEN rhs.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN '0122J00000023mbQAA'
    END AS 'RecordTypeId'
FROM RevisionHardware rh
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_Desktop rhd ON rhd.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_iSeries rhi ON rhi.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_zSeries rhz ON rhz.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_Server rhs ON rhs.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN LicenseMethod lmi ON lmi.LicenseMethodID = rhi.LicenseMethod_ISeriesID
LEFT JOIN LicenseMethod lmz ON lmz.LicenseMethodID = rhz.LicenseMethod_ZSeriesID
WHERE CASE
        WHEN rhd.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Desktop'
        WHEN rhi.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN 'iSeries'
        WHEN rhz.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN 'zSeries'
        WHEN rhs.RevisionHardwareID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Server'
    END IS NOT NULL
```

Destination Object:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test by deleting all the record types for the destination object and and performance has increased 10 fold.